# How to use local JSON assets to simulate API in Scala.js

Tags: json, scala, scala.js

I'm new to Scala and Scala.js and I want to experiment with handling JSON data. I'd like to simulate a server response by **returning the content of a JSON file local to my Scala.js project, parse it and work with the data**. What would be the best way to do so? Where should I place these files in my project tree, and how would I get their content?

Say that I have a file called `myJSON.json` containing something like

```
[
  {
    "ress": "AR",
    "lastDate": "2017-10-27 09:19:18"
  },
  {
    "ress": "JIM",
    "lastDate": "2017-10-27 06:57:15"
  },
  {
    "ress": "JOE",
    "lastDate": "2017-09-29 11:57:39"
  }
]
```

Can I place this file somewhere in my project so that I can read this file and then parse its content to use it somehow (could be displayed in the browser, logged to the console, etc...)? I guess I could use a tool such as [scala-js](https://github.com/MediaMath/scala-json) or something similar for parsing, but **accessing the file content in the first place is what I try to figure out**.

Note that I'm using scala-js.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code do you have? You're going to need to show us some code in order for us to help you.

Comment: @wheaties I added more details, but I don't have much more to show right now. Really just getting started and trying to figure out how to do some (I _guess_) basic things.

Comment: Note that this actually has nothing much to do with Scala.js (since that's just a language) -- the real issue here is what your *environment* allows you to do.  By and large, the browser deliberately makes it hard to access local files, since that's a security risk; there are some partial workarounds, but no great ones that I know.  That's why many Web tutorials have you construct a simple server as well as a client, when you're starting out...

Comment: As `Scala.js` compiles to `JavaScript` you would be better of just searching how to access a local file with JavaScript. Last time I checked, this was not possible, at least not in Browser-JS (for security reasons, else a JS from any webpage could just access all your personal files, upload them etc.). As that does not seem to have changed, you would need to have some server (e.g. using the `Playframework` or the like) and access the files from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others said above, Javascript that runs in the browser in general can't access the local filesystem. There are some exceptions:

- [**The File API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) lets you access files that the user has selected in the UI using `<input type="file" />` or drag-and-dropped into the browser window.
- [**The Filesystem API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) lets you access files the way you seem to want, but it is non-standard and is not supported in most browsers. It also seems that Scala.js has no typings for it, but I'm not sure.

[scala-js-dom](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom) has typings for the File API that you can use – search for `File` and `FileList` types in its source. Its API mirrors the Javascript API, so you will need to look for how exactly to do this in JS. Then translating it into Scala.js will be easy (or at least a different question).

If the File API does not work for your use case, another option is to use something like [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to easily serve your JSON files on localhost via HTTP.